# Java and kotlin in one spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradlew

I have a spring project on kotlin.
For faster development, it was decided to add another opportunity to develop on java.
But when we started adding java classes, we found that spring doesn't see them.

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.6.7"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.4.32"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.13.2")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.6.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    kapt("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(module = "junit")
        exclude(module = "mockito-core")
    }
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:3.0.1")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I know there are projects that support many languages within themselves.

I tried to connect java plugin, but nothing worked.

Comment: What source folder(s) are you using? I think it's usual to put Java classes in `src/main/java`, and Kotlin classes in `src/main/kotlin` — at least, that's how our projects work.

Comment: I put all classes in src/main/kotlin/com.example....  I don't want to create a separate package for this because it would be inconvenient to look at the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found such a solution, but it seems to me it is not quite right.

```kotlin
    configure<SourceSetContainer> {
        named("main") {
            java.srcDir("src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would be logical to try to fix issues with kotlin, but your question says kotlin works, yet java doesn't, do you mean `src/main/java` ?

Comment: @somethingsomething
I want to put java classes next to kotlin. For example StringUtil.java Collection.Util.kt. I don't want to create a separate package for this (the project will be inconvenient to read).